Can I reuse my character?
So I have a character in one of many books I'm working on and I wanted to know if I can just reuse the same character in different books and media if I created said character but each one is different in their own way? As in it's still the same character for the most part but a few things have changed (Like team name, allies, family, ect)

What do you mean, "reuse" but "different"?

As in it's the same character for the most part but some aspects are different.

Multiverse
We live in a post-IP world. There are many Batmans, many Micky Mouses, many Captain Kirks.
... or is it Batmen, Micky Mice, and Captains Kirk? Hmmm.
Everyone knows how reboots and multiverses work. It is no longer avant-garde and does not signal post-modern deconstruction of narrative structure.
Readers will accept it as a literary conceit – an author's choice in how the series is tied together.

It’s fiction. You can do whatever you want. I wouldn’t particularly worry about it. J. D. Salinger wrote about Holden Caulfield and his family several times before he wrote Catcher in the Rye, and while some of those stories were incorporated into the novel, others weren’t, and there are inconsistencies about the number and names of his siblings between these.
I’ve always thought it would be kind of fun to intentionally reuse a character across multiple stories but add in irreconcilable inconsistencies between appearances (the Simpsons does this to great effect, mixing in consistent backstory with contradictory elements of the stories).

Thanks. With my character, it's all different but kinda like a multiverse in a way?

I'm currently reading all the books by YA author Sarah Dessen. All her protagonists are 16-year-old teenage girls with troubled families going through an identity crisis. Over the course of their stories they all find friends or love and find out who they are.
Dessen's readers are buying her books because she describes a common experience for teenagers to go through, so the repetition is what sells her novels. It is part of her brand. But despite their macroscopic similarities all her stories are vastly different on a microscopic level. The exact experiences her protagonists have and how they find friends and find out who they want to be is completely new every time. Although I'm reading the same tropes over and over again, I keep being entertained by how Dessen varies them in a way that makes every story appear original and unique.
If you're retelling the same story with the same characters and all that changes is their name, costume, and superpower, the repetition is going to become old for some of your readers pretty quickly. But if every story is fresh and surprising, the similarities and repetitions will be what builds you a loyal fanbase.

Yeah, it's just the same name, but different everything (save for relationship cause I can't help it.) but otherwise yeah. Google was no help.
